# Is there any way I can find out my town's ranking?

Tags: die2nite

Is there a website or tool which allows me to see my town in Die2Nite ranked with other towns in respect to some criteria?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [this list](http://die2nite.hoah.org/town), but it's quite unofficial. Still, it works, as long as everyone submits their keys.

Comment: just a note that this list is very inaccurate, but the only option available.  Just ignore the rankings they give you though, all it really helps with is letting you compare total defence, people left alive and number of buildings built. Eeven the number of buildings ia a bit of a red herring, as each building is worth the same amount of points on those rankings yet they are certainly not all of equal value to your town :)

Comment: @desolation The creator of that site is actually quite open to constructive criticism. If you have any ideas on how to improve the ranking, you might try to contact them.

Comment: I have posted numerous suggestions on the world forums, which I assume he stil reads :-)  I have also seen numerous other posts saying a similair thing to myself.  I cant really give much constructive critiscism, becuase Pulse intended it to be a "how long they might survive" ranking.  I just dont think a complex ranking system like he has created is helpful at all, would rather see a list of Day Number, Total defence, Total Defence Items.  I may well try to contact him again, but certainly when there were threads about these rankings in the beta Pulse was not willing to budge